# How do you scroll a set number of pixels past an object?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I wanted to scroll to an object, but I wanted it to go, say, 50 pixels further. I know the following would work:

```
document.getElementById("foo").scrollIntoView();
document.documentElement.scrollTop += 50;
```

But that looks a bit bodgy. It's hard to read, and I suspect it will run slightly slower, as it's scrolling twice instead of once.

Is there a one-liner that does the same thing? Something like

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.getElementById("foo").fooDistance + 50;
```

I know `fooDistance` is wrong. What's the correct version?

I tried looking on [this list](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) but couldn't see anything that looked right.

Answer (score 0):

maybe [`Window scrollTo()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp) with [`element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element-relative-to-the-browser-window)?

```js
var posY = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
window.scrollTo(0, posY+50);
```

Comment: getBoundingClientRect().top is incorrect. It measures the location of an object as displayed on the screen, not the location of an object on the page.